# JPA: Is Map<Entity1,Set<Entity2>> possible?

Tags: java, jpa

I don't see an example anywhere so I am not sure this is possible. But basically, I am trying to see if I can bind a field in an entity to

```
   Map<Skill,Set<Rating>> ratings;


CREATE TABLE Worker (
  ID         BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,

);

CREATE TABLE Skill (
  ID   BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE WorkerSkillRating (
  ID       BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  WorkerID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  SkillID  BIGINT NOT NULL,
  Rating   INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (WorkerID) REFERENCES Worker (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SkillID) REFERENCES Skill (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Rating) REFERENCES Rating (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Rating (
  ID       BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  score    TINYINT NOT NULL,
  comments VARCHAR(256)
);
```

Entities

```
@Entity
public class Skill {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;


    public Skill(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Skill() {
        this.id = Math.abs( new Random().nextLong());
    }

}


@Entity
public class Worker {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // The open question
    public Map<Skill, Set<Rating>> ratings;

}

@Entity
public class Rating {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Byte score;
    private String comments;

}
```

Comment: Will you appreciate an explanation why it is not possible?

Comment: Is a Skill mapped to one and only Rating per Worker? If so, why would you need a Map?

Comment: @YairZaslavsky I could appreciate an explanation

Comment: @KumarM a worker has many skills and he may have been given many ratings on a single skill.

Comment: No. Not possible like that. Create an intermediate Entity that has a Set<Rating> field. There are many other posts on this site saying the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JSR-0038 the JPA spec. When using Map, the following combination are just allowed: Basic Type, Entities and Embeddables.

```
Map<Basic,Basic> 
Map<Basic, Embeddable> 
Map<Basic, Entity>

Map<Embeddable, Basic> 
Map<Embeddable,Embeddable>
Map<Embeddable,Entity> 

Map<Entity, Basic>
Map<Entity,Embeddable>
Map<Entity, Entity>
```

I don’t think there is pretty much deal to have a possible mapping in the way that you want but that is out of the specs and most of the providers follow them, I think that mapping is not very common at all.

> "worker has many skills and he may have been given many ratings on a
>   single skill. "

Then add to the skill class a `Set<Ratings>`, instead of nested directly in the map as the value of it.

Comment: I like this idea, but a skill+ rating only makes sense when associated with a worker.

Comment: If a worker have many skills, you could have a field Collection<Skill> in the Worker class, there is not problem to have this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It might not answer your question with the map but...

It looks like your rating table is unnecessary.

You could instead have

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
  ID         BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE Skill (
  ID   BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE WorkerSkill (
  ID       BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  WorkerID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  SkillID  BIGINT NOT NULL,
  score    TINYINT NOT NULL,
  comments VARCHAR(256)
  FOREIGN KEY (WorkerID) REFERENCES Worker (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SkillID) REFERENCES Skill (ID)
);
```

> Note I moved the rating information to WorkerSkill table.

Then you can map your entities per below

```
@Entity
public class Skill {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // Getter setters const etc

}

@Entity
public class WorkerSkill {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private int score;

    private String comments;

    @ManyToOne
    private Skill skill;

    @ManyToOne        
    private Worker worker;

    // Getter setters const etc

}


@Entity
public class Worker {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    public List<WorkerSkill> workerSkills = new ArrayList<>();

    // Getter setters const etc

}
```

Then you can access all worker's skill using `worker.getWorkerSkill();`

Comment: I came to that conclusion as well. There is a catch though: How to represent a worker who has a skill but no rating/review yet?

Comment: you would have to change WorkerSkill to have null scores in this case. Or you could assume they all start from 0.

Comment: There is the a problem with the approach above: This would load all skill+rating combinations even if all you wanted where just a Set of available skills. I need to be able to get at at both the small set of skills and produce an overall rating score for said skills.

Comment: Sorry Chris, didn't quite get the problem here. If the approach above, you could/would populate skills tables. Then you could/would populate workers table then you could/would populate worker_skill table either during saving a worker or as a standalone operation. On worker load, you would have a list of all the skills that worker has with or without ratings. You get that out of the box with JPA just putting the relationships in place but that doesn't constraint you to query for only rated skill for example.